# MySQL Query: WHERE $val(3) IN $table(2,6,3,8,9). How to make that query

Tags: php, mysql

So I have data saved in the table as comma separated values.

```
availability
6, 9, 11, 12
2, 6, 10
1, 2, 6, 9
```

And I need to get only rows where we have 9.

Any idea how can I make the query please ?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

Before starting to criticize in such a fashion, intelligent people will understand that OP may or may not be the original coder. Often, OP can be simply the person who has taken a project of somebody else and debugging / adding other functions to it. Not everybody does end to end coding alone in every project. But then, not everybody is sane and intelligent enough to understand such things as well.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service, please add the code you've already tried to the question, along with the errors/problems you're facing with it

Comment: "So I have data saved in the table as comma separated values." --- in plain English it can be translated as "how to make a mistake even before starting solving a task"

Comment: `Select * From XYZ Where availability like '%9%';` Please read about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: This is a classic case of RTFM ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php / http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE availability like '9,%'
   OR availability like '%,9'
   OR availability like '%,9,%'
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fd80/2)

Comment: But this will probably create a problem if I am looking for 1 (January), since I will have 10,11,12 for Oct, Nov, Dec as well.

Comment: i edited my answer ,please insert some data in fiddle and say where is problem

Comment: Do note that with larget datasets this will be extremely slow. What if I enter "19,"? What if I enter ",94"?

Comment: please look this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48f35b/1 i dont know where is your problem. make sure u have used my edited code. it works perfect

Comment: Thanks @echo_me. that's working perfectly. @ Anyone, that number we will get using date("n"), no way to have things like 19, in this case thanks for the point, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you store your data differently. You can solve it with mysql LIKE, but you have to throw a regex over that it can't be next to another number directly (so " " and ","). This is rather heavy tho.